# Reading File from directory and sort using ant

Tags: ant, build-process

I have a list of files in a directory . I have to read all the file names and extract the file name in a sorted order. How can I do that using ant script

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify the sort criteria. Lots of options available see the resource documentation in the ANT manual

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html

## Example

```
├── build.xml
└── src
    ├── data1
    │   ├── file1.txt
    │   ├── file2.txt
    │   └── file3.txt
    ├── data2
    │   ├── file4.txt
    │   └── file5.txt
    └── data3
        └── file6.txt
```

Running the project prints the list of files sorted in reverse order based on modified date

```
build:
     [echo] Files: /../src/data2/file4.txt:/../src/data3/file6.txt:/../src/data2/file5.txt:/../src/data1/file3.txt:/../src/data1/file2.txt:/../src/data1/file1.txt
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="build">

  <target name="build">
    <sort id="src.files">
      <fileset dir="src" />
      <reverse xmlns="antlib:org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.comparators">
        <date />
      </reverse>
    </sort>

    <pathconvert targetos="unix" property="srcFiles" refid="src.files"/>

    <echo message="Files: ${srcFiles}"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

Comment: What's the result type of `pathconvert`? How can the list of sorted files be used - like as `srcfile` in an `apply` task?

Comment: The "pathconvert" is designed to create a path string. If you want a reverse sorted list of files to be passed to the "apply" task then use the "srot" resource collection directly. See: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html